# Java: Receive answer from Windows Azure Service Bus Queue

Tags: java, azure

I'm trying to implement Request Response Queue using Windows Azure Service Bus Queue. I created two queues: Request and Response.

My client side send message to Request queue, then my server side take this message from Request queue, do something and put response into Response Queue.
The client side check Response queue if there are any messages. When I run only one client it's working fine.

When I run more then one client, after some time clients side don't pull off any message from Response queue. This queue for sure isn't empty, because client side check how many messages are there.

For receiving message I  use:

> ReceiveMessageOptions options = ReceiveMessageOptions.DEFAULT;
>
> options.setReceiveMode(ReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK);
>
> options.setTimeout(20);
>
> ReceiveQueueMessageResult resultQueueMessage = service.receiveQueueMessage(responseQueueName);
>
> BrokeredMessage receivedMessage = resultQueueMessage.getValue();

Any help would be appreciated,

Asia

Answer (score 0):

The clients are probably locking the messages but never deleting them.

As described in [How to Use Service Bus Queues](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/how-to-guides/service-bus-queues/#bkmk_HowToReceiveMsgs):

> In PeekLock mode, receive becomes a two stage operation, which makes it possible to support applications that cannot tolerate missing messages. When Service Bus receives a request, it finds the next message to be consumed, locks it to prevent other consumers receiving it, and then returns it to the application. After the application finishes processing the message (or stores it reliably for future processing), it completes the second stage of the receive process by calling Delete on the received message. When Service Bus sees the Delete call, it will mark the message as being consumed and remove it from the queue.

The example below demonstrates how messages can be received and processed using PeekLock mode:

```
ReceiveMessageOptions opts = ReceiveMessageOptions.DEFAULT;
opts.setReceiveMode(ReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK);
while(true)
{ 
     ReceiveQueueMessageResult resultQM = 
        service.receiveQueueMessage("TestQueue", opts);
     BrokeredMessage message = resultQM.getValue(); 
     if (message != null && message.getMessageId() != null)
     {
        try 
        {
           System.out.println("Body: " + message.toString());
           System.out.println("MessageID: " + message.getMessageId());
           System.out.println("Custom Property: " + 
                message.getProperty("TestProperty"));
           // Remove message from queue
           System.out.println("Deleting this message.");
           service.deleteMessage(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // Indicate a problem, unlock message in queue
           System.out.println("Inner exception encountered!");
           service.unlockMessage(message);
        }
     }
     else
     {
        System.out.println("Finishing up - no more messages.");
        break; 
        // Added to handle no more messages in the queue.
        // Could instead wait for more messages to be added.
     }
}
```

According to your application's logic, you have to decide whether you want multiple clients receiving messages from the same queue (in which case any client instance can receive any message), or if you want each client to have a distinct queue so it only receives messages specifically addressed to it.